# post only for form/small data or also for large data

Tags: rest, http, ftp, data-transfer

I googled quite a bit but did not find any useful answer. I have used post in the past to post some form data or some small-ish JSON payloads. Just curious, is post actually meant to transport large-ish data. Let us say 5 MB or are there better transport mediums (e.g. FTP). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP Post to transfer large data. Web applications that have a File Upload feature, for example, use POST to send files with several MBs.
Using FTB is also an option, but this selection of protocol (HTTP x FTP) depends on the requirements and anchitecture of your product.

Comment: so you think post is truly intended for large data - not just smallish (form json) payloads?

Comment: The HTTP specification doesn't impose a  size limit for the Post method. So, I would say that it's intended for all sizes of data.